# Jquery number category selector different minimum & maximum values for categoryNames

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set different min and max values for each category (Adults Children Bedrooms)

```js
$.fn.NCS = function(options) {

    $input = $(this);
    $originalPlaceholder = $input.attr("placeholder");

    var settings = $.extend({
      // Defaults.
      categoryNames: ["Adults", "Children", "Bedrooms"],
      categoryValues: false,
      minValue: 0,
      maxValue: 10,
      closeOnOutsideClick: true,
      showText: true,
      delimiter: ", ",
      align: "left",
      fade: true,
      useDisplay: true,
      showZero: false,
      callback: function(values) {}
    }, options);
```

Comment: I was looking for some PHP code to fix :(

Comment: set it up so that you use an array of objects where you set {name, min, max} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing the code I think you're using the NumberCategorySelector Jquery plugin, (which you should've specified instead of php)

A solution would be passing an array

```
var settings = $.extend({
            // Defaults.
            categoryNames: ["Adults", "Children"],
            categoryValues: false,
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: [10,20,30],
            closeOnOutsideClick: true,
            showText: true,
            delimiter: ", ",
            align: "left",
            fade: true,
            useDisplay: true,
            showZero: false,
            callback: function(values){}
        }, options);
```

then use the settings.Maxvalue as an array :

```
 $category = $(this).attr("category");
 if (settings.categoryValues[$category] <settings.maxValue[$category]) {
 ///etc
 }
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g8k1xhz9/)

Comment: how do I continue with this? category names are 
Adults -> maximum 10  Children->maximum 12  Bedrooms->maximum 6

Comment: You set the max value as an array   maxValue: [10,12,6], then you use it like this : settings.maxValue[$category] Here's an example : https://jsfiddle.net/g8k1xhz9/